# <TextArea> tag support for <font> tag

Tags: fonts, textarea

Text area tag is not interpreting . Instead, it is taking . I want to make it read  rather than .

I am trying to read  tag and display that text in text area. But not formatting is maintained in text area. So please tell what is the reason behind this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about the HTML textarea element there is no support for showing HTML content, it is purely text only. You can use for example a div element with the contenteditable attribute set to true

```
<div id="txt" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Or you can use any of the more complete editor solutions like for example [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/)

Comment: Not sure I understand you correctly but as you know the font tag is deprecated and you use css for this today. You can specify the style on each individual element with a style attribute which is probably what some of these editors do.